# SQL Join Query to Get Item Name , Date and Sum of Debit Balance where Debit balance Not Equal to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT dbo.items.NAME, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dbo.warehouse.date, 101)AS Date, 
       Sum (dbo.warehouse.debit)                    AS Quantity 
FROM   dbo.warehouse 
       INNER JOIN dbo.items 
               ON dbo.warehouse.businessunitid = dbo.items.businessunitid 
                  AND dbo.warehouse.itemid = dbo.items.itemid 
GROUP  BY dbo.items.NAME, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dbo.warehouse.date, 101)
```

SQL Join Query to Get Item Name , Date and Sum of Debit Balance where Debit balance Not Equal to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT i.NAME, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), w.date, 101 ) AS Date, 
       Sum(w.debit) AS Quantity 
FROM dbo.warehouse w INNER JOIN
     dbo.items i
     ON w.businessunitid = i.businessunitid AND
        w.itemid = i.itemid 
GROUP BY i.NAME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), w.date, 101) 
HAVING Sum(w.debit) > 0;
```

This assumes that `w.debit` is never negative.  (In financial applications, dollar amounts are often always positive.)  Of course, if it can be negative, you might want:

```
HAVING Sum(w.debit) <> 0;
```

or:

```
HAVING Sum(w.debit) < 0;
```

Depending on the circumstances.

In many other databases, you can use the alias in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING Quantity > 0
```

but SQL Server doesn't support this.

Also note the use of table aliases.  This makes it easier to write and to read queries.

Comment: be careful, to match question should be `HAVING Sum(w.debit) <> 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for having clause. Append this to your query:

```
HAVING Sum (dbo.warehouse.debit) <> 0
```

Quoting [HAVING (Transact-SQL) docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) -- *your sql looks like t-sql* --

> **HAVING (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.